# How to send an email with a formatted html table and message?

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email contains a fixed message and below it a formatted HTML table which gets the range values only if the total column "row[23]" is not empty, which means he's on shift.

Simply I am trying to send the productivity to my team in a table containing the members in duty, in the Google Sheet formula to reflect the internal productivity, but I need the script to only contain the row with values in the table format, I've tried to create a new HTML page and link it with the .gs script, I've tried to use library, I've tried to generate formatted HTML table script using websites and combine them.

```
function sendEmails2() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet6')

var startRow = 1; 

var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() 

var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:x18' );

var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {


var row = data[i];

 var emailAddress = 'sherif.gamal1611@gmail.'

var message = "Hi team, kindly check our prod till now as below " 

var Date= row[0];

var subject = 'Productivity Report' + " " + Date;

if (row[23] !="" );  {

//var htmltable =[];

var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'

var html table = '<table ' + TABLE FORMAT +' ">';


for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

 htmltable += '<tr>';

 for (col = 2 ;col<data[row].length; col++){



  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
 else
  if (row === 0)  {
  htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
 }

else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

   htmltable += '</tr>';
 }

  htmltable += '</table>';
   Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(htmltable);


  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{ htmlBody: htmltable});

   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
}
```

The spacing and padding in the mail I receive is in a bad shape, I wonder if it's possible to be aligned and have the same format in the sheet and the mail to contain a message before the HTML table and the table to only contains the rows which has values in the total column row[23] " column X".

Comment: thanks for responding, Ruben. 
Am digging deep into your reference as am really a beginner using script but am following and hope i get the required result.

Comment: @TheMaster, a fixed text massage before the table in the mail like : var message = "Hi team, kindly check our prod till now as below "

Comment: Try removing `table-layout:fixed` and provide a screenshot to show what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make everything a table and then make the borders around your initial message clear